# How to move excel sheet to another sheet after 2000 rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created a recipe in IFTTT to receive SMS and send it to google sheet. But IFTTT creates a new sheet after 2000 rows, basically it replaces the existing sheet/workbook with a new one. so all the data is lost.

Purpose: I am trying to use it to keep track of warranty of new mobile phones which I oem from China under my brand name. Each new mobile sends sms to a predefined number which I have at my office once after it is turned on after taking it out of the box.

I want to automate a process where the sheet automatically moves 2000 row of data to sheet #2 just as the 2000th row is filled and the sheet#1 is wiped for new content.

P.S I have zero knowledge about scripting/macro.

Comment: Do you think it is fair to say _I have zero knowledge about scripting/macro_, show no effort in research (at least) and ask to us "just do what I need"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will take items in range of A1 to Z2000 on sheet 1 and paste it under the 2000 rows on sheet 2, then deletes sheet 1. Be sure to use a xlsm file to be able to call the vba macro.

```
Sub Nafis()

   If Not IsEmpty(Range("A2000").Value) = True Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z2000").Copy _ 
        destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2000")
        Sheet1.Delete
    Endif
End Sub
```